# How to prevent attacks sql injection?

Tags: php, sql-injection

I would like to know how you can make your own site COMPLETELY secure to the attacks of type Sql Injection. I read that it would be enough to enable the magic quote gpc in the htaccess file. Is this enough? There are other tricks? How to understand if a script is open to Sql Injection? For example, this snippet is closed to the attacks sql jection?

```
$sql = $_REQUEST['id'];
$sql = mysql_real_escape_string($sql);
        $Query = "DELETE FROM Y WHERE id = ".$sql;
```

For example, large sites like facebook or google how to prevent this type of attack? Sorry for my english...

P.S. i'm not able to program with the paradigm OOP

Answer (score 0):

see here for better understanding sql injection attacks

http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html

and here for prevent sql injection attacks

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)